# Current through a load connected to a transformer

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, power

If I use a transformer the get a high voltage, the power of the transformer remains the same, as the current is reduced proportionally.

However, according to ohms law, the current through a resistor connected to that secondary side of the transformer will be the voltage divided by the impedance of the resistor.

But that is impossible, because this way both the voltage and the current felt by the resistor will increase, meaning an increase of power, while the power of the transformer remained the same, compared to the first side of it.

Please sort out my confusion over it.

Comment: If you don't have anything on the output side, there is no current flowing. If you have zero resistance on the output side you claim the current goes to infinity. Ponder a bit more about impedance matching in the problem.

Comment: When you said, "If I use a transformer [to] get a high voltage...the current is reduced." That does _not_ mean that the current through a resistor connected to the high-voltage output of the transformer will be less than the current through the same resistor if the resistor was connected directly to the lower-voltage power supply. What it means is, that _at any given moment in time,_ the current in the low-voltage winding will be $N$ times the current in the high-voltage winding where $N$ is the turns ratio of the transformer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a numerical example, maybe clearer.

I have a step-up transformer with ratio $m = 5$.
We place at the output of the transformer a resistor of $10 \Omega$.

At the input of the transformer we have a voltage source of $1 V$.

At the secondary of the transformer we therefore have 5 V. In the resistor the current is $5 V/ 10 = 0.5 A$.

On the other hand, at the input of the transformer, the current is $5 \times 0.5 = 2.5 A$.
The power supplied to the resistor by the secondary is $0.25 W$ At the primary the power is also $1 \times 2.5 = 2.5 W$

Now suppose the turns ratio is doubled $m = 10$. You will have $10 V$ at the secondary. The current through the resistor will be $10/10 = 1 A$ and the power will be $10 W$. In the primary, the current will be $10 A$ and the power will still be $10 W$. No contradiction.

Maybe your confusion comes from the phrase "transformer power remains the same". Indeed, it is the same in input and output (in the ideal case). But if you apply a higher voltage to a resistor, it will draw more power and the primary will supply more power.

Hope it can help and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Oh great! So having a higher ratio will not only increase the voltage at the secondary, it will also increase proportionally the current at the primary, and increase the power at both sides, not only at the secondary. Thanks a lot, my confusion is somewhat sorted. For now...

Answer (score 1):

We'll assume an ideal transformer here, which exhibits no internal losses.

The way to push more power into a resistor is to raise the voltage across it. But if we *restrict* or choke off the current flow through the resistor, we will decrease the power dissipated in it.

So, the step-up transformer does two things for us *at the same time*: it jacks up the voltage, while simultaneously choking off the current flow. These two things exactly cancel each other and the result is that the *power into the transformer* (primary current times primary voltage) equals the *power out of the transformer* (secondary current times secondary voltage).

Physically, this is a statement that an ideal transformer *conserves energy*. The easy way to understand this is as follows.

You may imagine a transformer to be like a pair of gears. the twisting force they convey is like voltage and the RPM they share is like current.

A step-up transformer is like a gear pair where the primary gear is small and the secondary is large. when we apply a twist (voltage) to the primary gear, it multiplies that twist by the ratio of the diameters of the gears and the resulting twisting force at the secondary gear is bigger.

But *at the same time* the small gear (primary) is turning at some speed (current) and the large gear (secondary) is turning at a speed which is *slower* by the same diameter ratio of the two gears!

Power in (current times voltage, or torque times RPM) at the input is the same as the power out (current times voltage, or torque times RPM) at the output. torque goes up, current goes down, power stays the same.

Comment: Could you please expand on the mechanism of this current choking? If a high voltage exists between the secondary coil ends, and the resistance of the load remains the same, what exactly is inhibiting the current from flowing through the resistor?

Comment: @Ahdriam, will edit for clarity soon. -NN

Comment: Thanks the analogy makes things clearer. But if The number of coils correspond to the diameter of the gear, voltage to torque, and current to rotation speed, how would you expand that analogy (if it is possible) to include the load on the transformer? Would it correspond to the mass of the second gear?

Comment: I can, but not today! -NN